# Does the UE5 FSemaphore structure work as interprocess synchronization?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, semaphore, unreal-engine5

The description of the structure on their documentation says "Generic representation of a interprocess semaphore" but I have read other stuff online that says otherwise.

Their documentation is rather sparse when it comes to multithreading/multiprocessing and I was wondering if anyone has used the FSemaphore object for synchronizing multiple instances of a UE5 application.